# XML parsing using C# for sibling element with namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've a complex XML and would like to parse it in C# using LINQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xml:space="preserve" w:embeddedObjPresent="no">
<w:docPr xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0">
    <w:displayBackgroundShape/>
    <w:view w:val="print"/>
    <w:zoom w:percent=""/>
    <w:defaultTabStop w:val="708.1365"/>
    <w:docVars/>
</w:docPr>
<w:body>
    <w:p xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Author_28_s_29_"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="T4"/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>Satyam</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T5"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Singh</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:t>,</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T6"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Disha</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:t>A</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T4"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>.</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T5"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Shah</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T7"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>,2,*</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:t>,</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T4"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Karan</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="T5"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Bhutwala</w:t>
    </w:r>
   </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

So I would like to get as:

Author_28_s_29_=Satyam Singh

Author_28_s_29_=Disha A Shah

Author_28_s_29_=Karan Bhutwala

.

.

So on.

I've tried couple of options to parse. The logic here can be taken as

parent().children.where(r).(t).value

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program of what you've tried, and explain what you expected vs what happened. (It would also *really* help if you'd format your XML so that the structure is obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

This xml is very strange. Perhaps there is an easier way, but I got only this:

```
 XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("1.xml");
XNamespace nms = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml";

    var author = xd.Root.Element(nms + "body")
                .Descendants(nms + "pStyle")
                .Single()
                .Attribute(nms + "val").Value;

    var arr = string.Join(" ", xd.Root.Element(nms + "body")
                .Descendants(nms + "t").Select(y => y.Value))
                .Split(',').Where(y => y.Length > 2)
                .Select(y => string.Format("{0}={1}", author, y.Trim()))
                .ToArray();

    foreach (var x in arr)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Out:

```
Author_28_s_29_=Satyam Singh
Author_28_s_29_=Disha A . Shah
Author_28_s_29_=Karan Bhutwala
```